# How to close a bat after a specific time without intrerupting the execution?

Tags: batch-file

I want to manage to execute and manipulate my bat file, but, în background i want a countdown so that after a specific time, no matter what, my bat calls another one that deletes it, or simply closes.

Also i want the bat file to show up on execution maximized. I have set /max after start command, but still minimized. I used în my bat /min and it worked, cant figure out why /max doesent work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it start maximized put this at the top of your script, below `@echo off`

```
if not "%1" == "max" start /MAX cmd /c %0 max & exit/b
```

I'll update this answer later with the other part, but I think opening a new batch with a timeout as soon as this one starts with `start /B` should help a lot.

EDIT

So this starts your script with a second script in it. That second script kills the first script and starts a third cmd to delete itself:

```
@echo off
if not "%1" == "max" start /MAX cmd /c %0 max & exit/b
set T=%TEMP%\sthUnique.tmp
wmic process where (Name="WMIC.exe" AND CommandLine LIKE "%%%TIME%%%") get ParentProcessId /value | find "ParentProcessId" >%T%
set /P A=<%T%
SET PID=%A:~16%
echo @echo off > killParent.bat
:: replace the 5 on the next line with any other number
echo timeout /t 5 /nobreak >> killParent.bat
echo start "" cmd ^/c timeout ^/t 1^^^&del "%%~f0"^^^&exit ^/b >> killParent.bat
echo taskkill /f /PID %PID% >> killParent.bat
START /B CMD /C CALL killParent.bat >NUL 2>&1
::any logic here instead of pause
pause
```

Place your code where the pause is and replace the 5 with the number of seconds you want to wait.

This does have the drawback of not being able to finish before the timer runs out, you can fix that by putting `echo title parentKiller >> killParent.bat` below `echo @echo off > killParent.bat` and putting

```
del killParent.bat
taskkill /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq parentKiller *" /T
```

at the end of your execution path, so at the bottom of your batch file normally. This would then look like this:

```
@echo off
if not "%1" == "max" start /MAX cmd /c %0 max & exit/b
set T=%TEMP%\sthUnique.tmp
wmic process where (Name="WMIC.exe" AND CommandLine LIKE "%%%TIME%%%") get ParentProcessId /value | find "ParentProcessId" >%T%
set /P A=<%T%
SET PID=%A:~16%
echo @echo off > killParent.bat
echo title parentKiller >> killParent.bat
:: replace the 5 on the next line with any other number
echo timeout /t 5 /nobreak >> killParent.bat
echo start "" cmd ^/c timeout ^/t 1^^^&del "%%~f0"^^^&exit ^/b >> killParent.bat
echo taskkill /f /PID %PID% >> killParent.bat
START /B CMD /C CALL killParent.bat >NUL 2>&1
::any logic here instead of pause
pause
del killParent.bat
taskkill /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq parentKiller *" /T
```

Comment: I'll test that tomorrow and return with results. Thank you, Dennis!

Comment: Hei!
I wanted to ask you about "if not "%1" == "max" start /MAX cmd /c %0 max & exit/b". What %1 means? %0 max & ecxit/b ? I want to understand what I am using, please.

The other part of the code is too complicated for me. :D But i try now to do a second bat with a timeout that call another one to delete them all after a specific time. Is your idea actually, but i think it is more simple.

I dont want to write something that i dont fully understand.

Thanks again!

Comment: this tests if parameter %1 is max, and if this is not the case this starts a maximized version of the current batch-file, giving it max as parameter %1, and closes the current window. Also, if you feel like this answer solved your problem, you should accept it by clicking the check to the left of it.